# Black screen after login, only recovery mode works

Tags: drivers, login, amd-graphics

Have spent a long time looking on the Internet but can not find a solution.

**current behavior**

After entering the password I have a black screen and keyboard seems unresponsive.

The caps lock has no effect on the led indicator but `ctrl` + `alt` + `F3` works but can not enter any text.

After opening terminal  it says.

```
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_ti
meout_secs" disables this message.
```

If I get into recovery mode I am able to login after starting the network and running normal mode but the screen will have a low resolution.

I am suspecting an automatic update which affected the ATI Radeon drivers (Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M) but I have no idea how to fix this. I tried to boot on 2 different older kernels from GRUB but still the same behavior.

[syslog](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rYJ8bFX-0SSPaDyc5zllCeGNyxEJXOB-/view?usp=sharing)

[history.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KbB1WVrrxz0ZjQ7vsJpqUAnae-ggB2iZ/view?usp=sharing)

**setup**

version

```
jb@jb-HP-ENVY-14-Notebook-PC:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

hardware

```
    jb@jb-HP-ENVY-14-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo lshw
    jb-hp-envy-14-notebook-pc   
        description: Notebook
        product: HP ENVY 14 Notebook PC (QB422PA#AB5)
        vendor: Hewlett-Packard
        version: 0585200000241A10001630100
        serial: CNU1242V9L
        width: 64 bits
        capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
        configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5335KV G=N L=CON B=HP S=PAV X=MIN sku=QB422PA#AB5 uuid=69FB2CC5-FEB5-7874-48C0-C32491CB0ED3
      *-core
           description: Motherboard
           product: 3385
           vendor: Hewlett-Packard
           physical id: 0
           version: KBC Version 93.0F
           serial: PCFYR00QE0V0NK
           slot: Base Board Chassis Location
         *-firmware
              description: BIOS
              vendor: Hewlett-Packard
              physical id: 0
              version: F.04
              date: 05/30/2011
              size: 1MiB
              capacity: 2560KiB
              capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
         *-memory
              description: System Memory
              physical id: 19
              slot: System board or motherboard
              size: 8GiB
            *-bank:0
                 description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
                 product: M471B5273DH0-CH9
                 vendor: Samsung
                 physical id: 0
                 serial: 803034A0
                 slot: Bottom-Slot 1 (Top)
                 size: 4GiB
                 width: 64 bits
                 clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
            *-bank:1
                 description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
                 product: M471B5273DH0-CH9
                 vendor: Samsung
                 physical id: 1
                 serial: 803034A1
                 slot: Bottom-Slot 2 (Under)
                 size: 4GiB
                 width: 64 bits
                 clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
         *-cpu
              description: CPU
              product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
              vendor: Intel Corp.
              physical id: 24
              bus info: cpu@0
              version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
              slot: CPU1
              size: 1496MHz
              capacity: 2900MHz
              width: 64 bits
              clock: 1333MHz
              capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts cpufreq
              configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
            *-cache:0
                 description: L1 cache
                 physical id: 26
                 slot: L1 Cache
                 size: 32KiB
                 capacity: 32KiB
                 capabilities: synchronous internal write-through instruction
                 configuration: level=1
            *-cache:1
                 description: L2 cache
                 physical id: 27
                 slot: L2 Cache
                 size: 256KiB
                 capacity: 256KiB
                 capabilities: synchronous internal write-through unified
                 configuration: level=2
            *-cache:2
                 description: L3 cache
                 physical id: 28
                 slot: L3 Cache
                 size: 6MiB
                 capacity: 6MiB
                 capabilities: synchronous internal write-through unified
                 configuration: level=3
         *-cache
              description: L1 cache
              physical id: 25
              slot: L1 Cache
              size: 32KiB
              capacity: 32KiB
              capabilities: synchronous internal write-through data
              configuration: level=1
         *-pci
              description: Host bridge
              product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
              vendor: Intel Corporation
              physical id: 100
              bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
              version: 09
              width: 32 bits
              clock: 33MHz
            *-pci:0
                 description: PCI bridge
                 product: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
                 version: 09
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=pcieport
                 resources: irq:24 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:c8700000-c96fffff ioport:c0000000(size=134217728)
               *-display UNCLAIMED
                    description: VGA compatible controller
                    product: Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
                    vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                    physical id: 0
                    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                    version: 00
                    width: 64 bits
                    clock: 33MHz
                    capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
                    configuration: latency=0
                    resources: memory:c0000000-c7ffffff memory:c8700000-c871ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c8720000-c873ffff
            *-pci:1
                 description: PCI bridge
                 product: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1.1
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
                 version: 09
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=pcieport
                 resources: irq:25
            *-pci:2
                 description: PCI bridge
                 product: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1.2
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:01.2
                 version: 09
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=pcieport
                 resources: irq:26
            *-display UNCLAIMED
                 description: VGA compatible controller
                 product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 2
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
                 version: 09
                 width: 64 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: latency=0
                 resources: memory:c8000000-c83fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
            *-communication
                 description: Communication controller
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 16
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
                 version: 04
                 width: 64 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
                 resources: irq:39 memory:c9704000-c970400f
            *-usb:0
                 description: USB controller
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1a
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
                 version: 05
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
                 resources: irq:16 memory:c9709000-c97093ff
               *-usbhost
                    product: EHCI Host Controller
                    vendor: Linux 5.8.0-50-generic ehci_hcd
                    physical id: 1
                    bus info: usb@1
                    logical name: usb1
                    version: 5.08
                    capabilities: usb-2.00
                    configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                  *-usb
                       description: USB hub
                       product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                       vendor: Intel Corp.
                       physical id: 1
                       bus info: usb@1:1
                       version: 0.00
                       capabilities: usb-2.00
                       configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                     *-usb
                          description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                          product: HP Integrated Module
                          vendor: Broadcom Corp
                          physical id: 3
                          bus info: usb@1:1.3
                          version: 3.06
                          capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                          configuration: driver=btusb speed=12Mbit/s
            *-multimedia
                 description: Audio device
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1b
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
                 version: 05
                 width: 64 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                 resources: irq:42 memory:c9700000-c9703fff
            *-pci:3
                 description: PCI bridge
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1c
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
                 version: b5
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=pcieport
                 resources: irq:27 memory:c8600000-c86fffff
               *-network
                    description: Wireless interface
                    product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
                    vendor: Intel Corporation
                    physical id: 0
                    bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
                    logical name: wlo1
                    version: 35
                    serial: 00:24:d7:b7:e5:60
                    width: 64 bits
                    clock: 33MHz
                    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-50-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 6000-4.uc ip=192.168.1.144 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                    resources: irq:40 memory:c8600000-c8601fff
            *-pci:4
                 description: PCI bridge
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1c.4
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
                 version: b5
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=pcieport
                 resources: irq:28 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:c8500000-c85fffff
               *-network
                    description: Ethernet interface
                    product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
                    vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                    physical id: 0
                    bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
                    logical name: eno1
                    version: c0
                    serial: 64:31:50:a2:87:aa
                    capacity: 1Gbit/s
                    width: 64 bits
                    clock: 33MHz
                    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=5.8.0-50-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                    resources: irq:41 memory:c8500000-c853ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
            *-pci:5
                 description: PCI bridge
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1c.7
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.7
                 version: b5
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=pcieport
                 resources: irq:29 memory:c8400000-c84fffff
               *-usb
                    description: USB controller
                    product: uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
                    vendor: NEC Corporation
                    physical id: 0
                    bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
                    version: 04
                    width: 64 bits
                    clock: 33MHz
                    capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                    configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                    resources: irq:19 memory:c8400000-c8401fff
                  *-usbhost:0
                       product: xHCI Host Controller
                       vendor: Linux 5.8.0-50-generic xhci-hcd
                       physical id: 0
                       bus info: usb@3
                       logical name: usb3
                       version: 5.08
                       capabilities: usb-2.00
                       configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                  *-usbhost:1
                       product: xHCI Host Controller
                       vendor: Linux 5.8.0-50-generic xhci-hcd
                       physical id: 1
                       bus info: usb@4
                       logical name: usb4
                       version: 5.08
                       capabilities: usb-3.00
                       configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=5000Mbit/s
            *-usb:1
                 description: USB controller
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1d
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
                 version: 05
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
                 resources: irq:20 memory:c9708000-c97083ff
               *-usbhost
                    product: EHCI Host Controller
                    vendor: Linux 5.8.0-50-generic ehci_hcd
                    physical id: 1
                    bus info: usb@2
                    logical name: usb2
                    version: 5.08
                    capabilities: usb-2.00
                    configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                  *-usb
                       description: USB hub
                       product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                       vendor: Intel Corp.
                       physical id: 1
                       bus info: usb@2:1
                       version: 0.00
                       capabilities: usb-2.00
                       configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                     *-usb:0
                          description: Keyboard
                          product: USB Receiver
                          vendor: Logitech
                          physical id: 1
                          bus info: usb@2:1.1
                          version: 12.10
                          capabilities: usb-2.00
                          configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=12Mbit/s
                     *-usb:1
                          description: Mass storage device
                          product: USB2.0-CRW
                          vendor: Generic
                          physical id: 3
                          bus info: usb@2:1.3
                          version: 38.82
                          serial: 20090516388200000
                          capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi
                          configuration: driver=ums-realtek maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
                     *-usb:2
                          description: Video
                          product: HP Truevision HD
                          vendor: QAD5L0SD
                          physical id: 6
                          bus info: usb@2:1.6
                          version: 21.05
                          capabilities: usb-2.00
                          configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=250mA speed=480Mbit/s
            *-isa
                 description: ISA bridge
                 product: HM65 Express Chipset LPC Controller
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1f
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
                 version: 05

             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:38 ioport:4088(size=8) ioport:4094(size=4) ioport:4080(size=8) ioport:4090(size=4) ioport:4060(size=32) memory:c9707000-c97077ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:19 memory:c9705000-c97050ff ioport:4040(size=32)
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0303
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device SYN1e4f
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 aux
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 8
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST9500325AS
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: BSM1
             serial: S2WE2RXL
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=a0d7452b
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: FAT32
                serial: cd55-c9e7
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 512MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: a5b7-15d6
                size: 511MiB
                capacity: 513MiB
                capabilities: primary fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                size: 464GiB
                capacity: 464GiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   logical name: /
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 8e1e6d62-f6d5-4d38-ad1a-11a944a3bce9
                   size: 464GiB
                   capacity: 464GiB
                   capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2020-12-08 13:08:44 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2021-04-24 13:42:44 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2021-04-24 13:42:53 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 9
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVDRAM GS30N
             vendor: hp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: VC03
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=open
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: a
          logical name: scsi6
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=ums-realtek
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: Multi-Card
             vendor: Generic-
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: 1.00
             capabilities: removable
             configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/sdb
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: OEM_Define1
       product: OEM_Define5
       vendor: OEM_Define2
       physical id: 1
       version: OEM_Define6
       serial: OEM_Define3
       capacity: 75mWh
```

EDIT: I ended-up reinstalling Ubuntu, issue when I update via Software Updater it ends up in the similar above case.

Comment: Has it always been like this or did it work and  now does this? If it did work before how long ago was the install?

Comment: Hi @David, it worked before and now does this. According to history.log, the auto install seemed to happen on the 18th of April. When I restarted the PC several days later around the 20th of April I was having this issue.

Comment: There may have been a kernel upgrade. Try choosing an older kernel from Grub on start up/

Comment: I tried this already but same behavior. Let me edit the post

Comment: In the end I think this was a hardware failure but not sure 100%, I changed my PC now